# go through data and replace 'X' by blanks

Tags: google-apps-script

I am aware this might be an easy question but I am trying to figure out an easy way to go through an array containing numeric data (1,3,15,...) and 'X'. And whenever you encounter a 'X' replace it by '' (blank)....any tips ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to search a value of `x` from 2 dimensional array with 20 columns and 200 rows.
- When the searched value was found, you want to replace the value to the empty value of `""`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script 1:

This is a simple script. This is the destructive method.

```js
// Create sample 2 dimensional array
var row = 200;
var col = 20;
var ar = Array.apply(null, new Array(row)).map(function(_, i) {return Array.apply(null, new Array(col)).map(function(_, j) {return j})});

// Search and replace value
var x = 3; // search value
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < ar[i].length; j++) {
    if (ar[i][j] == x) {
      ar[i][j] = "";
    }
  }
}
console.log(ar); // or Logger.log(ar)
```

#### Sample script 2:

In this script, the process cost is lower than that of above script. This is the nondestructive method.

```js
// Create sample 2 dimensional array
var row = 200;
var col = 20;
var ar = Array.apply(null, new Array(row)).map(function(_, i) {return Array.apply(null, new Array(col)).map(function(_, j) {return j})});
  
// Search and replace value
var x = 3; // search value
var res = ar.map(function(e) {return e.map(function(f) {return f == x ? "" : f})});
console.log(res); // or Logger.log(res)
```

#### Note:

- When you use above script at Google Apps Script, by replacing `console.log(res)` to `Logger.log(res)`, you can see the result at Log.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Benchmark: Loop for Array Processing using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/848aeafaac1ec676900bb78e3ce220b6)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, Thank you so much for this detailed answer... but my array is a 2D array... sorry I did not mention this. Would you know how to do the that in that case ?

Comment: I would like to go through 20 different columns and around 200 rows and pick up the 'X' to replace them by nothing '"".....but only the 'X' as there are other numbers which I would not like to erase

Comment: @danymalibu Thank you for replying. From your question, I couldn't notice that you are using such 2 dimensional array. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike no need to apologize, it is kind of you to take the time for this problem...I have tried your solution but I still see the 'x' in the data in the Logs ...

Comment: function todayIntoTomorrow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var xremoved = ss.getSheetByName('Xremoved');
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("L:BD");
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  Logger.log(values);

  
  var x = 3; // search value
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
    if (values[i][j] === 'x') {
      values[i][j] = "";
    }
  }
}
Logger.log(values); 
}

Comment: when I do Logger.log(values); I still get the original array defined

Comment: My bad. I did the Logger.log() before the solution you suggested

Comment: @danymalibu Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.